# Color Blind Red->Orange Green->Blue

Tags: colors, visual-studio-code, accessibility, color-theme

I'm Red-to-Green colorblind and working with VS Code. I would like to override all Red and Green text colors throughout the entire editor. Red would be changed to Orange, and Green would be changed to Blue.

Android Studio (IntelliJ) has this feature. Is there a way to do it in VS Code?

Comment: I don't have an answer, but if your color blindness isn't too extreme, there are now glasses that will improve your ability to differentiate the colors, and you may not need to modify color coding.  They filter out light wavelengths for the color overlap so the colors can be better differentiated.  See https://www.allaboutvision.com/conditions/color-blind-glasses.htm.  They aren't cheap, but they improve everything you see, so the justification is quality of life rather than coding convenience.

Comment: I googled "vscode colour blind themes" and there seems to be a fair few themes already made for people in your situation. You could maybe try one of those?

Comment: As a fellow red/green color blind person, I can confirm that it is very difficult to find themes that are not hostile to people like us. Even the themes that claim to be color-blind friendly do things such as having yellow-on-white text. I don't know about normal people, but that is a hellish combination for some of us color-blind people to have for important things like braces and brackets!